# NodeJs - Access Git index on Windows

Tags: windows, git, node.js

I am trying to use the nodejs module, [gift](https://github.com/sentientwaffle/gift) to read the index of a Git repo. I chose 'gift' because it seemed the most promising on Windows. Does anyone know how to get the status of the Git repo using this module? I basically just want to perform a status command on my Git repo.

> $ git status

Are there any other nodejs Git Modules that work well on Windows?

Thanks!

**Solution**

After looking through the source I found that Status is an object which is attached to Repo. You use it as described in my selected answer.

*Windows caveat* - I had to [add git to my system path](http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/) and then **REBOOT.** Gotta love windows :\ Even after adding git to my system path and testing it out in cmd.exe, gift kept throwing error:

> command failed: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Once I rebooted all was well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the status like this

```
git  = require 'gift'
repo = git "path/to/repo"
repo.status(callback)
```

The callback receives `(err, status)`. Status has properties

```
status.clean
```

boolean, true if working tree clean

```
status.files
```

Object - The keys are files, the values objects indicating whether or not the file is staged, tracked, etc.

Each file has the following properties:

- type - "A" for added, "M" for modified, "D" for deleted.
- staged - Boolean
- tracked - Boolean

Source for this information: [the documentation](https://github.com/sentientwaffle/gift).

Comment: Thank you. I figured this out by going through the source. However, status(callback) always calls the my callback with the following 'err': ommand failed: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Git is installed here and I have 'git' set in system path. So cmd.exe git works. Wonder what's up?

Comment: @Nick is git added to the Path for your user only or for the whole system? You might need to set it at the system level.